# How do you get an model to fadeIn/fadeOut when it is changed using ng-animate?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate

I have an element on my webpage that shows the most recent item. Every few seconds I add a new element to the top of my items array and I would like the old item to fade out and the new one fade in.

The problem is my code currently isn't fading in the new item (it is fading out the old one) and is pushing down the old one where I would like the old one to fade out and once that animation is finished the new one to fade in in the same place.

HTML

```
<body ng-app="testApp">
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <button type="button" ng-click="refresh()">Refresh</button>
    <div ng-animate="{enter:'animated fadeIn', leave:'animated fadeOut'}" ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:1">
        {{item}}
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

JS

```
angular.module('testApp',[]);

angular.module('testApp').controller('testCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.items = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3'];

  $scope.refresh = function() {
    var newItems = $scope.items.slice(1).concat($scope.items.slice(0,1));
    $scope.items = newItems;
  };

});
```

CSS

```
@import animate.css
```

I have a very simplified version of what I want to do here: http://jsfiddle.net/ErhQB/

In my real app the "Refresh" button is a timeout (And the code in $scope.refresh in wrapped in $apply).

I'm fairly certain I am doing this incorrectly but I'm not sure how to trigger animate events or I would create a $scope.item model that I would update with the item I want to show but I'm not sure how to use that with ng-animate (or any other way for that matter).

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: I would try to change the style of the items so that they all are on the same line. I mean set container's `display` to `relative`, and the items' `display` to `absolute`.

Comment: Your fiddle is using AngularJS 1.1.5,  It is recommended to use 1.2+ if possible as the animations have been completely rewritten to make it easier.

Comment: @TheSharpieOne Thank you, I upgraded and now I have animations working. For anyone else who needs help check this out: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html It was very helpful!